# How to fix boot issue ? VFS: cannot open root device "mapper/x" or unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: 12.04, boot

I've got ubuntu 12.04 running as a virtualserver on virtualbox.

Last night there was a power surge and this morning I can't boot my virtual server.

I get a long error message. I picked this up:

VFS: cannot open root device "mapper/ubuntu--server-root" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6

when I do:

ls /dev/mapper

I get>
control
ubuntu--server-root
ubuntu--server-swap_1

I can mount manually by doing

'mkdir /foo;mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--server-root /foo'

I don't know what to do but I installed a tool and extracted this log http://paste.ubuntu.com/7119904/

Comment: When you say you ran those various commands, what do you mean?  Did you get an initramfs rescue shell ( don't think so based on the first error ), or did you boot from a live cd to run those commands?

Comment: Hi! I boot from the live cd to run these commands. I'm right now looking into your answer below, and I'm really happy to see it running. I just got stuck into updating initramfs but I'll put more info in a couple of moments.

Comment: Others might see this error if they have run out of diskspace on the /boot partition, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot. Not in your case if it's only started after the power cut.

Answer (score 1):

Your most recent kernel, 3.5.0-47-generic, is missing its corresponding initrd image.  Pick the previous kernel version from the boot menu and once the system comes up, run `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 3.5.0-47-generic` to create the initrd, and `sudo update-grub`.