# Preseeding 3.16 hardware enablement kernel requires manual update-initramfs

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation, preseed, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm preseeding a 14.04 Trusty install, on a machine which requires a driver fix from the 3.16 kernel, which is the one which goes with 14.10 Utopic. The easiest way to get this kernel is to install the corresponding hardware enablement stack:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/trusty/main/base/linux-generic-lts-utopic

When I add the PPA and install the package after installation, it works out fine. However, when I add `linux-generic-lts-utopic` to the `pkgsel/include` line in my preseed, I get a kernel panic on first boot into the installed system (happens in Parallels and on the actual hardware). It turns out that I have to use the GRUB menu to first boot the default 3.13 kernel, and [then run](https://askubuntu.com/a/436403/98081):

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 3.16.0-17-generic
sudo update-grub
```

After doing this, it can boot 3.16 just fine.

This seems super janky. Is this a regression in the hardware enablement stack, or a problem with the installer, or something missing from preseed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your preseed file like? Did you try adding an update-initramfs command as a late command?

Comment: I have done the late-command, and that works, but it's a hack and should be unnecessary if the package and/or installer were configured correctly.

Comment: There's an option called `base-installer/kernel/image` for selecting the kernel to be installed. Tried that?

Comment: I tried `image` and `override-image`. Neither had any effect— the package doesn't get installed. I tried also installing the package via `pkgsel`, but then I just get the kernel panic.

Comment: Note that `update-initramfs -c -k all` in the late_command does _not_ work. You have to call out the exact version to generate for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a generalized version of the hack, do:

```
update-initramfs -c -k $(ls /lib/modules -1 | tail -1)
update-grub
```

This can be done directly from the late_command, or via a script that the late command invokes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the lts-utopic d-i images linked from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/trusty/ rather than trying to hack it up in a preseed from a d-i booting with 3.13?